# How to add new sections to app config file in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

I'm using Virtual Studio 2017 to develop a WPF application. I want my application to get a table of data from server and to save the table to the app configuration file. Each row of the table will be a section in the app configuration file. The problem is I cannot find any way to save data like that.

Example: We can use `GetSection` method to get a setting section but there seems to be not any method like `AddSection` or `SetSection` to add a new section.

I wonder if WPF supports this.

Comment: app.config is just an XML file so where is the problem? ... the bigger problem is that you shouldn't do this from app itself as normally app is installed in the place where non admin user should not have write permission

Comment: I've updated the question. We can use `GetSection` method to get a setting section but there seems to be not any method like `AddSection` or `SetSection` to add a new section. This is the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to store data in a configuration file? it is not their purpose. You should consider storing this data in a different file.

Comment: Why do you want to update the configuration file at runtime...? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You have various options. It's not obvious which framework version you are using. Since .NET Core, there is no *app.config* file anymore (by default). It's replaced with *.settings* files.

**app.config**

1. You can modify the .config file directly (XML) - only recommended to add elements like sections
2. Use the `ConfigurationManager` class ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=net-5.0#examples)) to read/write data and create sections
3. Use `XmlDocument` (or any other technique to handle XML data) to handle the XML content directly

The XML handling is quite complex, even when using the `ConfigurationManager`. There are better solutions, like JSON files, that are far more convenient.

**.settings**

1. Use the Visual Studio Settings Designer GUI
2. use the API of the `ApplicationSettingsBase` class ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019#access-or-change-application-settings-at-run-time-in-c))
3. Edit the code-behind file manually

As the name *.settings* implies the intention of those files is to store settings and not application data. Of course you can use the .settings file to store any data, but then make sure to create a dedicated file for such data (by adding a new item to your project) so that you don't mix settings with data.

Since .settings is property based (key-value-pair), storing data sets like tables or other data structures (e.g. tree) is not very convenient.

The common way to store application data is to serialize C# objects to JSON text objects ([JSON serialization and deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview?pivots=dotnet-5-0)) or binary format ([Serialization (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/)), simply write data as structured plain text file like .csv files, XML and when speaking of tables, of course, we instantly think of a database (e.g. simple file based db like SQLite).